# space is neglected when passed a string by URL

Tags: php, html

I am using the following code to display a hyperlink inside a table:

```
echo "<td><a href=http://www.smstoneta.com/show.php?opcode=TCP Y".">".
        $row['num_y']."</a></td>";
```

The hyperlink is displayed successfully but when I click on the hyperlink, the URL is

> www.smstoneta.com/show.php?opcode=TCP

instead of

> www.smstoneta.com/show.php?opcode=TCP Y

Why am I not getting the full URL?

Comment: You need to look at urlencode... http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [urlencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
$opCode = urlencode('TCP Y');
echo "<td><a href=http://www.smstoneta.com/show.php?opcode=".$opCode.">".$row['num_y']."</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

You need [URL Encode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) spaces to make them working in links.

Here is manual for PHP function [urlencode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php)

```
$safe_url = urlencode('http://www.smstoneta.com/show.php?opcode=TCP Y');
echo "<td><a href=" .$safe_url. ">" .$row['num_y']. "</a></td>";
```

BTW, more readable (no concatenation needed) version to echo such strings is:

```
echo "<td><a href='{$safe_url}'>{$row['num_y']}</a></td>";
```